# Simulating more powerful motors in Gazebo?

Tags: gazebo, ros2, motor, differential-drive

Is there a way to get Gazebo to recognize the power of a motor?

I have a couple of powerful motors in my differential drive robot that given the weight of the robot I should be doing 16 feet/second max speed.   In Gazebo it just plods along at a far slower pace.    I have tried setting the max revs.  The only way I have been able to increase the speed seems to be setting the weight lower, which isn't realistic.

The robot was modeled in SolidWorks, and converted to Ros2 using the converter plugin.  Rviz shows mass correctly.  Inertia values are from SolidWorks using the real material weights of the parts.

Are there some parameters I should be setting in gazebo_ros2_control?